# File names in remote are different than locally

Tags: git, azure-devops, azure-repos

I have a git repository on Azure DevOps.
I have noticed that the file names on the DevOps portal are different than in my local repository. However, when I try to `git pull` it says that there repo is in sync. The git history is the same, so it seems to be true.
Here's an example of a difference:
Locally, the file name is `myFile.json`. In DevOps the file name is `myfile.json`.

Which version is the true one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is documentation that explains your issue and ways to resolve it: [Git case sensitivity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/case-sensitivity?view=azure-devops)